can I get rclone to 'only' download non recursively?
I'm currently using rclone to download a dataset off the internet archive - it needs a newer version version of rclone and I'm running v1.60.1-DEV on ubuntu server. Rclone's faster and slightly more reliable than the IA client.and lets me download multiple files at once ideally I'm trying to run separate instances on various systems I manage to speed things up a little and not overlapping would be good.
The dataset that I'm currently trying to download is split between into 9 zipfiles, 0-9 on the root directories, lower and upper directories with zip files labelled a-z each.
What I'd like to do is download only 0-9.zip without individually specifying files from the root.
What I'm doing now with 12+ hour downloads per file is running the 'lower' case folder on the assumption that it'd be done before the rest is.
I've configured rclone to use IA as the remote so I have the command rclone sync IS:stack-exchange-images stack-exchange-images to download the entire repo, and  rclone sync IS:stack-exchange-images/lower stack-exchange-images/lower for the lowercase files, assuming the checksum check will catch the files that are already downloaded.
How can I exclude the 'upper' and 'lower' subdirectories and only download files in the root directories??

Have you consider to use curl. AFAIK it can download in parallel and use wildcard (kind of)?

Yes but this makes automation a LOT easier - this is a test run for other things. I also already run rclone for a few other things so I can tie this into stuff I have running now.

OK, at the end it's up to you. Just check this command: curl -L -Z https://archive.org/download/stack-exchange-images/[0-9].zip -o '#1.zip' :)

and yeah, I considered wget and curl - I also use this system to do, say backups for my server so while this is a specific, testable case, there may be other usecases where I can't use curl. rclone is comically flexible. In this case I don't control the remote end so I can't move around the files

I did a few experiments - and the filters seem to be the 'best' way to do it. As with any rclone command, its worth running these with the dry run option first. You can also test these filters using the rclone ls command which is a lot faster.
clone sync -p  IS:stack-exchange-images stack-exchange-images/ --exclude=/*/
Hypothetically If I wanted to exclude specific directories the command below would work. This would be nice for selective exclusions.
rclone sync -p  IS:stack-exchange-images stack-exchange-images/ --exclude=/upper/ --exclude=/lower
